# Run step to open browser in cucumber / selenium test once before running all scenario examples then run step to close browser afterwards

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber

Apologies for poorly worded question. I am new to test automation and selenium / cucumber BDD and am trying to create a demo project that runs some maths expressions using google and validates the results. I want to use a scenario outline so have ..

```
Scenario Outline: Enter a maths expression
    Given User enters the maths expression <expression>
    When the user clicks the Search button
    Then The result of <expectedResult> is returned  
Examples: 
    | expression | expectedResult |
    | 4+4 | 8 | 
    | 5^3 | 125 |
```

I had my steps to open the chrome browser and navigate to google in the @Before method like ..

```
@Before
public void setup() throws Throwable {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\xxx\\chromedriver.exe");
    this.driver = new ChromeDriver();
    this.driver.manage().window().maximize();
    this.driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    this.driver.manage().timeouts().setScriptTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.get("https://google.com");
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    //agrees to the terms and conditions
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"L2AGLb\"]/div")).click();
}
```

When I run my feature it works but for every example in the Scenario Outline it runs the before steps (as appears to be expected behaviour from reading online) i.e. browser opens and closes for each example.

Ideally I would want the browser to open once at start, run through all examples and then close at end. Is there an appropriate method annotation that I can use to achieve this. I have tried to find the answer online but not had any luck. One post mentioned using @BeforeSuite but I just for errors when I tried to use this. Also I tried to use the @Background annotation but this did the same thing as it seems this runs for every scenario example.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Was my answer clear? Is that what you were looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct in your assertion. The Cucumber Hook `@Before` will execute methods tagged with this annotation before the first step of each scenario [See: [Cucumber Reference]](https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/api/). Obviously, if you do not want to open and close the browser before and after each scenario, then you can't add that code there. Unfortunately, Cucumber does not have a hook to run "*Before Suite*" like JUnit or TestNG have. So, you cannot run something before all or after all like you can on those unit test platforms.

A trick I have used is to initialize the driver and then store it as a global variable in a utility class. This way, I can reuse the same instance for an entire test session. Also, you can create an *init* scenario and run that will your scenarios.

```
@StartBrowser
Scenario: Start browser session
  When I initialize driver
  Then open browser
```

In the code...

```
public class BrowserInitStepDefinitions {
    @When("I initialize driver")
    public void initializeDriver() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\xxx\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriverUtils.setDriver(new ChromeDriver());
    }

    @Then ("open browser")
    public void openBrowser() {
        WebDriver driver = WebDriverUtils.getDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.yourwebsite.com");
    }

    @Then ("close browser")
    public void closeBrowser() {
        WebDriver driver = WebDriverUtils.getDriver();
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

```
public class WebDriverUtils {
    private static WebDriver driver;
    public static void setDriver(WebDriver webDdriver) {
        if (driver == null) {
            driver = webDdriver;
        }
    }
    public static WebDriver getDriver() {
        if (driver == null) {
            throw new AssertionError("Driver is null. Initialize driver before calling this method.");
        }
        return driver;
    }
}
```

Lastly, when you call your scenarios, just remember to include these scenarios first.

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(plugin = {"pretty", "html:target/cucumber-report.html"},
        features= "features",
        glue= {"whatever"},
        tags= "@StartBrowser or @MyTest1 or @MyTest2"
        )
public class TestRunner {
    // code omitted
}
```

You could (and most likely should) create a scenario to close your browser and reclaim any resources that you might've used during the execution of your tests.

Comment: Thanks hfontanez. I tried to incorporate your code into my StepDef class but get a few errors such as 'Type mismatch: cannot convert from void to WebDriver' on the OpenBrowser method. I guess that is because the getDriver method in WebDriverUtils is declared void? I changed the type of getDriver to WebDrive from void, but there are other errors like ''The method setDriver cannot be declared static; static methods can only be declared in a static or top level type". Sorry my java knowledge is not good so not sure how to resolve these. But will have closer look tomorrow.

Comment: Sorry.. I wrote the code directly here. I fixed the `WebDriverUtils`.

Comment: That's awesome. Thanks a lot. Will look at it tomorrow. Already closed Eclipse :-)

Comment: Hi. I made the chgs you suggested but still getting errors .There are no errors initially with BrowserInitStepDefinitions cls but WebDriverUtils has "The field driver cannot be declared static in a non-static inner type, unless initialized with a constant expression" against the private webDriver variable. Against the 2 mthds I get ."method .. cannot be declared static; static methods can only be declared in a static or top level type". I can get rid of the errors by removing the static mdifier but then I see errors on the BrowserInitStepDefinitions cls. "Cannot make a static reference to ..

Comment: You created _WebDriverUtils_ as an non-static inner class. It is supposed to be an outer (normal) class. I even separated the code inside their own set of ``` to make it clear.

Comment: I forgot to include the step for _closeDriver_. Updating Step Def class.

Comment: Ok, thanks for that. I hve no errors now. I had to import import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber; to get rid or error on @RunWith(Cucumber.class). Sorry what is supposed to go inside the testRunner class? I just added that  code at top of my SearchFeature class. What should be in place of 'code ommitted'? At the moment when I run it, it just does the same thing i.e. open and closes the browser for each example and doesn't seem to recognise that step defs exist for open browser and close browser.

Comment: @chucknor just leave it empty

Comment: Ok, sorry you are probably losing interest/patience at this point, but its still not  working. It doesn't recognise that step definitions have already been defined for the Steps 'open browser', 'I initialize driver' etc. Was the class BrowserInitStepDefinitions supposed to be inside my SearchFeature class? I noticed you left off the ^ and $ around the tags for steps in step definition file. I added these but these methods still don't run. I added println statements within these to check they are being called and they aren't.

Comment: Sorry I think I must have done something fundamentally wrong, but I just have the BrowserInitStepDefinitions inside my SearchFeature step Def class, but its never getting instantiated is it?

Comment: No. They need to be separate classes.

Comment: Ok, thanks. That scenario seems to be running. I had to uncomment the close browser method otherwise it wouldn't be able to run the other steps. Now it throws a nullPointerException error on the first example  in scenario outline. Is this because it doesn't have the web driver instance? I am still declaring a new WebDriver instance at the start of my SearchFeature file like WebDriver driver. But does this need to be done differently now that the BrowserInitStepDefinitions class creates the driver?

Comment: Sorry also, in your _CucumberOptions statement you had .. tags= "_StartBrowser or _MyTest1 or _MyTest2". Do I need to annotate my scenario outline with @MyTest1 or give it another name and have that in my _CucumberOptions?

Comment: You should replace my fake tag names with the ones you would like to run. Don't forget to create a scenario to close the browser at the end.

Comment: I've done that thanks. But do you know why I would be getting the nullPointerException (comment above)? Its the driver instance isn't it?

Comment: make sure you provide the correct path for the driver `exe` file here `"C:\xxx\\chromedriver.exe"`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241699/discussion-between-chucknor-and-hfontanez).